# Eclipse automatically opening some files in system editor

Tags: java, eclipse

Was finding this problem with Eclipse(Kepler) over the last week, so downloaded Eclipse (Luna) and checked out the relevent project into an entirely new workspace.

I'm using *.str files for a particular project (they are standard editor files anyway - short for 'string').  But Eclipse wants to open such files as macVim files:

[image]

I have NO file associations set for *.str files:

[image]

...althought I do use macVim to open them in the underlying operating system. So I change the system editor to TextEdit and Eclipse happily now wants them to open in TextEdit - but I want to open them in the eclipse editor! (appart from anything else, I've got to develop an editor plugin for *.str files.

How can I convince Eclipse that it can open *.str in it's own editors without having to resort to the system editor?

EDIT - follow the answers - my understanding is this.  If Eclipse doens't know what the file is, it will ask the system. If you ask it to open in a particular editor it will overlay that information on that particular file, and to make it happen in general (and change the icon) you need to add a file association.

Comment: Have you tried right click -> open with -> text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a a File Associations for '*.str' and set the Associated Editor to 'Text Editor'. Eclipse will use this for files that you have not yet opened.

For files that you have already opened Eclipse will be remembering the editor you last used, so for these right click on the file and use 'Open With > Text Editor'. You should only have to do this once.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file, select open with, and there should be three options (Text Editor/System Editor/Default).  Selecting text editor *should* associate it with eclipse (from within eclipse only) in future.

Comment: Upvoted because you had most of the answer -but I accepted greg's because it gave me slightly more information.